# WPF Datepicker - Bolded Dates

Tags: wpf, datepicker

Is there any way to set a series of dates that will be displayed within the DatePicker as bold (or otherwise highlighted)?

**=UPDATE=**
Apologies, seems I have not explained myself sufficiently.  I am looking to get outlook-similar behaviour with the calendar popup on the WPF DatePicker.  An example is as follows; [image: calendar example]

All dates are still selectable and the **bolded** dates are shown irrespective of any current selection.  The purpose of these bolded dates are to aid the user in selecting a date and or to represent items of interest.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Do you have found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Will crossing out work? if so, you could use BlackoutDates (you can have multiple `CalendarDateRange` )

```
<DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="2/1/2011" End="2/10/2011"/>
</ DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

or from code

```
calendar1.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(
        new DateTime(2011, 2, 1),
        new DateTime(2010, 2, 10)
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple dates like this

```
<DatePicker Name="MonthlyCalendar"    
    SelectionMode="MultipleRange"     
    DisplayDate="3/5/2010"    
    DisplayDateStart="3/1/2010"    
    DisplayDateEnd="3/31/2010"    
    FirstDayOfWeek="Tuesday"    
    IsTodayHighlighted="True"    
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Margin="15,39,88,19">
    <DatePicker.SelectedDates>    
        <sys:DateTime>3/5/2010</sys:DateTime>    
        <sys:DateTime>3/15/2010</sys:DateTime>    
        <sys:DateTime>3/25/2010</sys:DateTime>    
     </DatePicker.SelectedDates> 
</DatePicker>
```

For more info check these links

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/563/

http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: i have expanded the original question to further clarify